# Drupal 7 Views with custom template exposed filters doesn't showing

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-theming, drupal-templates, drupal-exposed-filter

I have a view and customize it with a template named views-view--myviewname--page.tpl.php.
My problem is that exposed filters doesn't showing when loading the page. But in preview in view editing screen showing as expected.
Is there a solution about this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure you are printing $exposed somewhere in your template file. In the default template file (https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!views-view.tpl.php/7) this is done using the following PHP code:
2. In your View's advanced settings, ensure you have "Exposed form in block" set to "NO" as in this screenshot http://cl.ly/image/1A3A3h0k3437.

Comment: Thank you very much. Solved with your first answer with $exposed.

Comment: Thanks for the second tip. You saved my day